# Integrate Twilio components without flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex, twilioflexwebchat

I will like to use the twilio messaging, voice, chat, channels, taskrouter, proxy, but I dont want to use Flex. Can I create a new app in .net for example and integrate all components and create something like flex or I need the flex webchat plugin? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is 100% possible. Flex is an application framework which connects all the relevant underlying Twilio API's and SDK's that handle the commonalities of a contact center (the framework) and lets the business focus on their unique aspects like configuring intelligent routing to agents based on their business logic, a consolidated agent user interface, and overall instrumentation of the contact center.